# DropDownListFor displaying all elements of List<List<String>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to use `@Html.DropDownListFor` to add selections to multiple drop down lists.

**View**

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.questions.Count(); i++)
{
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Questions</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.questions[i].Question)

            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">    
               @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.answers[i].Answers, new SelectList(Model.hold[i]))
            </div>  
            <hr />
        </fieldset>
}
```

This iterates through all the questions in my Model and displays the question.  The drop down box is used for the user to select answers to that question.  Since the number of questions and answers to those questions are dynamically created by the admin user I can not simply make static lists and insert them into the Drop Down List.

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //get the list of questions from db
        var q = (from questions in db.questions select questions).ToList();
        var answersList = (from answer in db.answers select answer).ToList();
        List<List<string>> aList = SplitAnswers();

        QAViewModel qa = new QAViewModel{questions = q, hold = aList, questionAnswers = answersList};

        return View(qa);
    }

   public List<List<string>> SplitAnswers()
   {
       List<List<string>> aList = new List<List<string>>();
       List<string> populate = new List<string>();
       var answersList = (from answer in db.answers select answer).ToList();
       var q = (from questions in db.questions select questions).ToList();

       //Group answers by questionId to use in the view
       for (int i = 0; i < q.Count(); i++)
       {
           for (int x = 0; x < answersList.Count(); x++)
           {
               if (answersList[x].QuestionsId == q[i].Qid)
               {
                   populate.Add(answersList[x].answer);
               }
           }
           aList.Insert(i, populate);
       }

       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test" + aList[1]);
       return aList;
   }
```

I'm using a `aList` (of type `List<List<string>>`) so that i can store `populate` (of type `List<string>`) at each element of `aList`.  However, each drop down list ends up showing all the elements of `aList`.

I am not sure if I am misusing `List<List<string>>` or if I am somehow adding all the elements of `populate` at every element of `aList`.

**UPDATE**

By changing the index of `Model.hold` in `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.answers[i].Answers, new SelectList(Model.hold[1]))` I can see that each element of this list holds all the answers.

Comment: I think you would be better off using `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` here.

Comment: @entropic I am getting the same result using a Dictionary

Comment: You would be better of creating a Question view model that contains the properties of the question and a `SelectList` of the answers associated with that question

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is how I originally had this, but due to changes that were required of me I was forced to create a separate models for Answers and Questions.  I do however use a QA View Model so that I can interact with both of my models on the view.

Comment: What I mean is keep your data models but create a view model for `Question` that used in your view (just as you have done for `QAView Model`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I do have the code working now but I will give your solution a shot and upvote you if it works @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I have figured out a fix to this problem.  I ended up using an array of List.

...

```
    List<string>[] populate = new List<string>[30];
```

..

```
   for (int i = 0; i < q.Count(); i++)
       {
           populate[i] = new List<string>();
           for (int x = 0; x < answersList.Count(); x++)
           {

               if (answersList[x].QuestionsId == q[i].Qid)
               {

                   populate[i].Add(answersList[x].answer);
                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("answers " + i + " " + answersList[x].answer);
               }
           }
           aList.Add(i, populate[i]);
       }
```

This works by creating a `new List<string>` each time a new questions answers need to be stored.  Then those answer strings can be stored at that element of the array.  Each time a questions answers are added to the array I add that element into my `List<List<string>>`.

Then in the view this line of code does not need to be changed.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.answers[i].Answers, new SelectList(Model.hold[i]))
```